# How can I add custom messages to strerror?

Tags: c, error-handling

I'd like to improve my error handling when programming in C and use the mechanism used in `errno`.

The `errno` variable is modifiable so I can probably use my own error codes.

Now I'd like to associate a message with my error code. Is it possible to add strings to the array containing the messages of `strerror()` or should I code my own message array?

Maybe a better solution exists?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to add new errors or error messages. The "variable" `errno` is modifiable so you can set it to one of the standard errors. If you want a custom error message, why not simply *print* the actual custom error message?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I'm programming a library, I'd like to let the user handle the error how he wants to.

Comment: Then you should really only use one of the [standard errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html), even if there's no perfect match.

Comment: or you have your own `myliberrno` and `mylibstrerror()` in the library

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ... and provide a brief documentation about the meaning of the error codes returned and the context they appeared in.